# How to auto paste copied text when web page gets load?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, asp.net

I just wanna know, is there any method/technology to paste a copied text into an `input tag` automatically when the web page gets load. Can we do this using any technology(Server-side or client-side)?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What where your findings?

Comment: No, the website does not have access to your clipboard.  You need a browser plugin for that.

Comment: @jrswgtr I don't have any idea about it. I just googled it but nothing found.

Comment: In what case would you get data from the user clipboard?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

Comment: @jrswgtr Thanks for the link. Can you tell me one thing, why this question has negative votes. There are no 
similar questions on Stackoverflow. Isn't it useful?

Comment: Btw. I'm pretty sure that what you are trying to do is impossible for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell it is possible using the clipboard API, however for security the browser will ask the user if they wish to allow the action to occur (at least in Chrome).

Another caveat is that the tab will need to be in-focus (active) at the time of the call as well. Access to the contents of the clipboard is also gated behind the Permissions API.

- Source 1: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi
- Source 2: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_clipboard_readtext

It may be worth considering [document.execCommand('paste')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) if working within the context of Internet Explorer, although this is depreciated in most browsers.

```
navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => {
    document.getElementById('someInputId').value = text; 
});
```